# How to reduce the number of clusters produced by the Markov Clustering Algorithm?

Tags: natural-language-processing, hyper-parameters, clustering, cosine-similarity

I have used the Markov Clustering Algorithm (MCL) to cluster tweets, based on their similarity. However, I got a too high number of clusters, and most of the clusters have only one tweet. Any suggestions to reduce the number of clusters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to reduce the number of clusters produced by the Markov Clustering Algorithm (MCA) will **depend on the specifics of your data** and **how you want to cluster it**. However, some general tips that may help include:

- One way is to **pre-process your data** to remove noise and outliers. This can help to make your data more amenable to clustering and make it more likely that meaningful patterns will emerge.
- Some methods that may be effective in reducing the number of clusters produced by MCA include **downsampling the dataset**, using a smaller value for the clustering parameter (such as the number of iterations), or using a threshold value to filter out small clusters.
- Another approach is to play with the MCL parameters, such as the **inflation rate**, to see if that has an effect on the number of clusters produced. try increasing its value, this will lead to fewer, but larger clusters.
- Use a different **similarity measure**.
- you could try running MCL multiple times with different **random seeds** to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the implementation you're using, you can adjust the *granularity*, which will influence how many clusters you will get.

See [this description of MCL](http://micans.org/mcl/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you mean I adjust inflation parameter of mcl to get better clusers? Is that what you mean by granularity?

Comment: No, granularity is not the same as inflation. Are there no other parameter you can adjust?